# A density function that matches the $k$ smallest elements of $n$ uniform samples

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let me apologize in advance as this feels like a homework question, though I've tried without success to work through the relevant integrals.  My question is:  given positive integers $k$ and $n$ with $k<n$, does there exist a closed-form density $f$ on the unit interval such that, if I draw $k$ independent samples from $f$ (and then sort them left to right), the resulting points follow the same distribution as if I were to draw $n$ samples uniformly from the unit interval, and take the $k$ smallest elements?

I am aware of work on "order statistics", but the relevant results that I have found all deal with the case where the $k$ samples are not drawn independently from a single density, but rather, they are drawn in an ordered fashion from a joint distribution on $[0,1]^k$.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is possible at all!

Suppose that $n = 3$ and $k = 2$, and let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be the order statistics of a sample of random variables uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Then $\mathbb{P}(X_1>t)=t^3$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_2>t)=1-(1-t)^3$. Suppose that $Y_1,Y_2$ are the order statistics of a sample drawn from a distribution with CDF $F$. Then $\mathbb{P}(Y_1>t)=(1-F(t))^2$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y_2>t)=1-(F(t))^2$. Trying to match these probabilities gives $F(t) = 1 - t^{3/2}$ on one hand, and $F(t) = (1 - t)^{3/2}$ on the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover the density of f from that of its order statistics by choosing a random order stat with probability 1/n.  If k=2, n=3 this means that f would have to have density $\frac {3x^2  + 6*x(1-x)} 2 $ where the terms in the numerator are the densities of the 1st and 2nd order statisics from 3 draws of a uniform.  Now check that this doesn't work, e.g. $H^2$ is not the distribution of the minimum of 3 uniforms, $H$ being the cdf.